# Why does my Finite Difference approximation not work?

Tags: finite-difference, computational-physics

I am trying to find out the magnitude of the acceleration of my object based on non-uniformly sampled 3D position data. I'm using the standard approximation of the 2nd order derivative on a non-uniform grid (see e.g. [here](http://iwi.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/root/1992/JEngMathVeldman/1992JEngMathVeldman.pdf?origin=publication_detail), page 121):

$$ 
f'' \approx 2 \cdot\frac{h^+ f_0 - (h^- + h^+) f_1 + h^- f_2}{h^+ h^- (h^+ + h^-)}
$$

where $h^-$ is the first sample interval, $h^+$ is the second sample interval, and $f_n$ are the sampled points.

I'm trying to implement it in the following way:

```
class ComputeAcceleration
{
    Vector3D prevPosition;
    Vector3D prevPrevPosition;
    float prevTimeStep;

    float acceleration;

    // This function gets called every time step with the time step
    // since the last data input as argument.
    void Update(const float timeStep)
    {
        float doubleTimeStep = prevTimeStep + timeStep;
        Vector3D currentPosition = getCurrentPosition();
        Vector3D accelerationVector = prevTimeStep * currentPosition - 
                                      doubleTimeStep * prevPosition + 
                                      timeStep * prevPrevPosition;      
        accelerationVector  *= 2 / (doubleTimeStep * prevTimeStep * timeStep);
        acceleration = sqrt(accelerationVector.X * accelerationVector.X +
                            accelerationVector.Y * accelerationVector.Y+
                            accelerationVector.Z * accelerationVector.Z);

        prevPrevPosition = prevPosition;
        prevPosition = currentPosition;
    }
}
```

I can't find the error in this, but when I plot this in real-time, I get a curve that doesn't resemble acceleration at all, but rather speed, in some jerky way. I plotted it against the speed (which I know to be correct), and it looks roughly like this:

[image]

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

Comment: You only plot the magnitude of velocity and acceleration. To get the speed from 0 to some level and back to 0 you need to accelerate and deccelerate. That shows up as (at least) two spikes. Why do you think your plot is implausible?

Comment: More concretely, the actual differential relation between velocity and acceleration cannot be verified with the plot as the direction information has been lost. But you can figure out that for speed=0 over an extended period of time, acceleration has to be 0 as well, and your plot shows that. BTW, the implementation of the finite difference formula looks OK to me.

Comment: I am only interested in the magnitude of the acceleration, that's right. 
I should have mentioned the following though: rotational acceleration can be largely ignored, nearly all speed is linear. Therefore, when the speed is constant and nonzero, I expect the acceleration to be (nearly) zero. Instead, it's all over the place. That doesn't seem right...

Comment: If `GetCurrentPosition()` takes variable time, that introduces random errors in the actual timestep size. Same for any action after having taken the time. As a result, the computed acceleration cannot be expected to be zero for constant velocity.

Comment: In fact, I'd recommend to sample position and time together, within a dedicated function, to avoid discrepances between the two.

Comment: That could very well be it! When my object is perfectly still, the acceleration still shows small fluctuations, which would be explained in this way.

Comment: fluctuations when "perfectly still" imply that `GetCurrentPosition()` output is also noisy by itself. Such noise gets amplified by numerical differentiation. Known phenomenon.

Comment: So it seems that your tests use accelerations that are so small that they are in the same order of magnitude as their noise level. So you either have to increase the actual accelerations used in your tests or decrease the noise level. For the latter, you might want to increase the number of (vector) samples and fit a second order polynomial to them, or use a (correctly weighed) moving average for the (vector) acceleration.

Comment: Thanks, seems all plausible. I got most of that, except the weighed moving average thing... Could you please specify?

Comment: For that, keep a (fixed) number of previous `AccelerationVector*timestep` vectors and compute their sum, divided by the sum of their timesteps. That's the moving average. From the resulting vector, compute its magnitude as usual.

Comment: If you are successful, please do not forget to post an answer.

Comment: Correction: In the above moving average calculation, replace all mentions of `timestep` by `doubleTimeStep`, that's the relevant weight.